# Can i make this slide image auto play

Tags: javascript, html, css

```
<div id="thumbcarousel1" class="carousel slide custom_slider" data-interval="false">
            <div class="carousel-inner">
                <div class="item active">
                    <div data-target="#carousel" data-slide-to="0" class="thumb"><img src="img/logo/logo1.png"></div>
                    <div data-target="#carousel" data-slide-to="1" class="thumb"><img src="img/logo/logo1.png"></div>
                    <div data-target="#carousel" data-slide-to="2" class="thumb"><img src="img/logo/logo1.png"></div>
                    <div data-target="#carousel" data-slide-to="3" class="thumb"><img src="img/logo/logo1.png"></div>
                    <div data-target="#carousel" data-slide-to="4" class="thumb"><img src="img/logo/logo1.png"></div>
                    <div data-target="#carousel" data-slide-to="5" class="thumb"><img src="img/logo/logo1.png"></div>
                </div><!-- /item -->
                <div class="item">
                    <div data-target="#carousel" data-slide-to="6" class="thumb"><img src="img/logo/logo1.png"></div>
                    <div data-target="#carousel" data-slide-to="7" class="thumb"><img src="img/logo/logo1.png"></div>
                    <div data-target="#carousel" data-slide-to="8" class="thumb"><img src="img/logo/logo1.png"></div>
                    <div data-target="#carousel" data-slide-to="9" class="thumb"><img src="img/logo/logo1.png"></div>
                    <div data-target="#carousel" data-slide-to="10" class="thumb"><img src="img/logo/logo1.png"></div>
                    <div data-target="#carousel" data-slide-to="11" class="thumb"><img src="img/logo/logo1.png"></div>
                </div><!-- /item -->

            </div><!-- /carousel-inner -->
            <a class="left carousel-control" href="#thumbcarousel1" role="button" data-slide="prev">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span>
            </a>
            <a class="right carousel-control" href="#thumbcarousel1" role="button" data-slide="next">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span>
            </a>
        </div>
```

I have code for sliding image but I want to auto play slide.
Here I can play slides with next and previous button.

Comment: you can change it through js.

Comment: Set `data-interval="0"` for required items.

Comment: where the code for the sliding functionality, are you using a plugin? wheres the js?

Comment: @atmd  m using bootstrap carousel slider

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Data attributes data-interval in bootstrap is

> The amount of time to delay between automatically cycling an item. If
>   false, carousel will not automatically cycle.

```
Change data-interval="false" to true or 1000 (1 sec) , 4000 (4 sec)
```

Comment: great thanx @Kornkrit Leelhaphunt